# heroku + github path error in the log - cannot find the file path

Tags: python, github, heroku, discord, cloud

I deployed my github master branch to heroku. One of my code tries to access a file in the `misc` directory under the same branch. However, the log on heroku shows that the file does not exist. Please see the screenshot as follows:

[image]

Comment: Well, does the file exist?  What does your code do?  What does it look like?  You seem to be using a different path separator.

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Windows-style backslashes as your path separators, e.g. something like this:

```py
with open("foo\\bar.txt") as f:
   ...
```

or this:

```py
with open(r"foo\bar.txt") as f:
   ...
```

Backslashes as path separators don't work on Linux.

Use forward slashes instead, which works both on Linux and on Windows:

```py
with open("foo/bar.txt") as f:
   ...
```

Better yet, use [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/library/pathlib.html#module-pathlib) to join path segments:

```py
import pathlib

directory = pathlib.Path("foo")
with open(directory / "bar.txt") as f:
   ...
```

Or [`os.sep`](https://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.sep):

```py
import os

with open(os.sep.join("foo", "bar.txt")) as f:
   ...
```